# Fill polygon shape with color in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need to draw shape filled with special color in Corona SDK.
I'm trying draw vector map, where shapes will be as buildings.
The problem is object retuned by display.newLine() don't have setFillColor() method.
So, vector shape is empty (I see background through it), only stroke color can be changed via line:setColor().
How can I fill polygon shape with color?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few polygon fill algorithms.

Have a read here :
http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/
http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/outprims/polygon6.htm

And there is a nice implementation in Code Exchange!
http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/polygon-fill-and-point-polygon-detection

Comment: Sorry, I need many buildings, so, I think, fill shapes manually will greatly reduce perfomance. Now I found subject feature in MIAO framework.